# Bootstrap Increases overall page size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had a report which loads around `2000-2500 rows` using basic `HTML table` , it use to take around 5-10 secs and content size was around 5MB [as per chrome network statistics].

Now when I implemented same report using `bootstrap classes` so that it would look nice, it took around 25-30 secs to load same report with content size around 25MB.
I googled and found many reasons for the same and implemented all of it like gzip compression,`minified css`,`js` .Still load time remains the same also there are no images used in my report its just text in table

```
<!--Old HTML--> 
<div>
  <table>
      <tr>...nested tables & html simple buttons with no classes</tr>  
  </table>
</div>

<!--NEW HTML :-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-n">
       <table class="table table-condensed table-hover mytable">
              nested tables + bootstrap button 
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give us an example of your html, maybe a table row from your bootstrap and non-bootstrap version each?

Comment: NEW html : <table class="table table-condensed table-hover view_table"> ..
 Also each table wrapped in div.row and col-lg-n*
OLD html: <table> ..

Comment: @Vibhas it will be easier to understand if you edit your answer instead.

Comment: That's an overly large jump for Bootstrap - I use CDN for the CSS/scripts and it adds around 1-2 seconds max

Comment: Bootstrap has a lot of css that is loaded but not used, might wanna try customizing bootstrap so you only get what you need.